# Some records missing while insert into DB2/400 database using C#

Tags: c#, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have web site developed using C# and hosted on IIS, which inserts records into a IBM DB2/400 database. The connection is made using 'iSeries Access ODBC Driver'.

The records are inserted with in a loop and sometimes some records get missing in the DB2/400 file. No error is being fired.

Ex: No. of records 5

1 - Inserted

2 - Inserted

3 - Missing

4 - Inserted

5 - Inserted

Can someone please tell me what could be the cause for this and how to overcome this please?

Thank you!

Edit:

```
    try
    {
        // Select Statement here
        // Some other Insert statements here


        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
        sql.Clear();
        sql.Append("INSERT INTO LIBRARY.TABLE ");
        sql.Append("(Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4) ");
        sql.Append("VALUES ");
        sql.Append("('XX','" + YYYYY + "'," + ZZZZZ + ", '5' ");
        sql.Append(") ");

        DataBase.Execute(sql.ToString(), conn);
        }

// Some other Inserts here

    catch (Exception ex)
         {
        log.Write(ex.Message);
    }

//In DataBase Class



   public static void Execute(string sqlQuery, OdbcConnection conn)
    {

        OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandText = sqlQuery,
            CommandType = CommandType.Text
        };

        odbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some code where you think the issue may be originating from? To increase the chances of someone replying, read the how-to-ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you prove that "no error is being fired" ?  Cannot see this from the code sample provided.

Comment: Hi mao, didn't include the try/catch earlier in the sample. My bad. Code is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you parsed your input fields and ensured that all special characters are escaped? Numbers and dates are in the correct culture settings?

Have you checked if all values are inside their limits. Including the total size of the sql command string?

And have you checked that you are counting the field sizes in the rigth units? One common mistake is counting UTF-8 chars instead of their byte representation, if the DB field limit is set in 8bit chars.

Comment: Hi crumble,

Yes, I do replace any special character if in the variable before sending it to the SQL.

I didn't know there is a size limit to the sql command string.

When I re run the code with the same values (the values - I save in a separate SQL server) it inserts all the records.

Comment: The same machine with same client settings? Or do you see a different behaviour in test and production system?

Comment: And don't forget to check if you are using the same order of your inserts. Maybe a trigger rejects you data silently. Break on all exceptions in your debugger. Maybe your client catches an exception outside of your DB code

Answer (score 0):

Do not concatenate variable values into the SQL string if you can avoid it. Instead use parameter markers like this:

```
foreach (var item in Items) {
  sql.Clear();
  sql.Append("INSERT INTO LIBRARY.TABLE ");
  sql.Append("(Fld1, Fld2, Fld3, Fld4) ");
  sql.Append("VALUES ");
  sql.Append("('XX', ?, ?, '5')");

  DataBase.setParm(XXXX);
  DataBase.setParm(YYYY);
  DataBase.Execute(sql.ToString(), conn);
}
```

You may have to rework your Database class to set the parameters, but using parameters for variables rather than just concatenating them in will remove the issues that you can have with data that contains things like commas and quotes.

Comment: Thanks jmarkmurphy, will try that too. But how come it work when I re run with same values? 
When the user reports this (some records are missing) I try to replicate it with same values (that is saved in a SQL DB) and it works fine.

Comment: Without seeing a log, and the real values, I can't answer that question. Sometimes users sanitize what they tell you. When users tell me something that I can't replicate I tell them to call me again when it happens again, and to be careful to capture the exact cause if possible. Sometimes that is very hard to do as the issue isn't found out immediately. I also always log error conditions (that is missing from this code). SQL will happily ignore any errors that you don't explicitly trap.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Look your log, no doubt you have information into
2. Try to verify if your conn is open into your 'Execute' method (may be connexion can be not open, timeout etc...), something like this :

if (conn.State != conn.Open)
{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Open();
}

3. Control YYYYY max lenght, YYYYY must not contains quote (otherwise you must replace quote by double-quote) and for ZZZZZ variable control it's never empty (i suppose this column is a numeric or a Date or a timestamp because you dont use quote into you concatenation)

4. Dont forget to close you connexion after your job
5. For security you should be use Parameterized query like [here][1] 
6. If you can, you should use 'IBM i Access for Windows' driver for you connexion (search IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll) its better for performance
```

Have a good day!